# Object possibly null despite checking

Tags: typescript

Why is TS complaining

> Object possibly null

despite my check?

```
let sum = (data: [...(number | null)[]]): number => {
  let result: number = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    if(data[i]!==null){
      result += data[i]; // here is complain Object possibly null
    }
    
  return result;
};

console.log(sum([1, 2, null, 4]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is accessing a property of an object via key variable, TS does not recognize that both statements refer to the same value. You can store the value in a temporary constant to fix this:

```
const item = data[i];
if (item !== null) {
  result += item;
}
```

But I would not recommend using `for` loops anyway. Either use `for ... of` or a functional approach using `filter` and `reduce`.

```
for (const item of data) {
  if (item !== null) {
    result += item;
  }
}
```

Examples of various types of access that rightly or wrongly may cause errors:

```
const o = {
  x: 12 as number | null,
}
let key = 'x' as keyof typeof o;

if (o.x != null) {
  console.log(o.x + 1); // OK
}

if (o.x != null) {
  doSomething();
  console.log(o.x + 1); // Wrong but allowed
}

if (o[key] != null) {
  console.log(o[key] + 1); // Error
}

function doSomething() {
  o.x = null;
}

const arr: (number | null)[] = [12];

if (arr[0] != null) {
  console.log(arr[0] + 1); // OK
}

if (arr[0] != null) {
  doSomething2();
  console.log(arr[0] + 1); // Wrong but allowed
}

let i = 0;
if (arr[i] != null) {
  console.log(arr[i] + 1); // Error
}


function doSomething2() {
  arr[0] = null;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: ah you are referring to before `if` condition check and afterwards usage; if `data[i]` changes after if condition `item` still refers to old data right?

Comment: @john Not, quite. TS does not appear check if there is anything that can happen in-between check and usage. In this case there are no other statements, so it should be relatively safe, but imagine a `doSomething()` call before the `+= data[i]` and that function modifies the array.

Comment: OK I will check, no what I meant in docs there are many such `if` checks, I will check later if it applies to each of them or not: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html.

Comment: This particular checking issues appears to be limited to array access via an index variable, actually. For regular object properties, that would be allowed, even if it is wrong. I updated the answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: @H.B. (TS noob): isn't your 3rd and 2nd if basically doing same, why error in only one of them?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Because one uses a compile time constant key, the other uses a variable which could change, unless the compiler would check if that variable is `const`. (If those are the cases you mean)

Answer (score -1):

> WARNING: If the iterable object has a similar getter, then the first check in the if condition will call it once and then the assignment will call it a second time. The value can change between the if and the assignment. e.g.: `Math.random() > 0.5 ? null : 42`

You could use a [Non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#:%7E:text=Non%2Dnull%20assertion%20operator&text=post%2Dfix%20expression%20operator%20may,with%20null%20and%20undefined%20excluded.):

```
result += data[i]!;
```

Since you can 100% say in this context this is not null.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAzgrgthAvBAFAEwIZgwLggbQDpiUA7eAIxACcIAfCc4YASnwF12W9y4rbEAPggBvAFARJEUJGohYwMD0o0kEAAwBuCVIBmAe1ooZEAJZqtZiAB4ImbIVCkA5mAAWmswGovLHVKlTXVR7DHxTdggAQkRkJlZRfwDkuQVIL2RQ8PYozwB6PIg3GhAzKAgAY304AAdgDFNSCAB5CgArEArIGv0oKFMKYABPRhhmJICAXzEkuTAYaibUsbBtSe0xKtIofVBHfWcUWDgUfABGABoIACYr%20KuAFi4WbSA)

Comment: This is not true, for example with getters such as `const foo = { get bar(){ return Math.random() > 0.5 ? null : 42; }}`. It's trivial to create similar examples for iterables.

Comment: He checks for not null. How is this related to your example?

Comment: If the iterable object has a similar getter, then the first check in the if condition will call it once and then the assignment will call it a second time. The value can change between the if and the assignment.

Comment: Good point! I'll add this warning to my answer. However he did provide primitives in his question.

Comment: Typescript can't know what values the function will be called with. So long as the types match up it's valid code and Typescript needs to cover every legal case.